# Is this a proper (performance-wise) way of scanning directories and caching paths to an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### What am I trying to do

I'm trying to scan a disk and save (cache) all the paths of files and directories into an array so that I could perform a quick filename / directory name search later on.

### Implementation

I'm using a Node.js module called [walkdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walkdir).

```
cacheDisk () {
  let searchDir = 'C:/'
  let cache = []

  let options = {
    "max_depth": 5,       // only recurse down to max_depth. if you need more than no_recurse
    "track_inodes": true  // should be used with max_depth to prevent infinite loop. On windows or with hardlinks some files are not emitted due to inode collision.
  } 

  let paths = walkdir(searchDir, options, (path) => {
    cache.push(path)
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(cache)
    this.findItem(cache)
  })
},

findItem (cache) {
  let filename = 'file_1.txt'
  const matches = cache.filter(element => element.includes(filename))
  console.log(matches)
}
```

### Questions / Problems:

FYI: I only need it to work in the latest Chrome (it's an Electron app)

- Is using `cache.push(path)` a good way (performance-wise) to save paths to the array or is the module already doing it for me and I'm just repeating this action on every iteration? It takes about 30 seconds and 500-800 MB of RAM on a core i7 to finish that caching operation for my ssd with 1 million paths

---

- Is using `cache.filter(element => element.includes(filename))` a good / safe way to find an element in an array that can potentially be ~10,000,000 paths in length?

---

- When I'm trying to scan disk's root (e.g. `C:/`) I get 2 slashes after the disk letter in every path (e.g. `C:\\Program Files\test`). But when I'm scanning something like `C:/test/` everything is fine. I guess that's Node's doing? How do I avoid that? (do I just replace all `\\` with `\` in all the paths afterwards? e.g. `cache.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\")`)

Comment: Sounds like a job for a hash table

Comment: @bugs is it going to be more efficient / faster?

Comment: In V8, Maps generally have `O(1)` complexity for standard CRUD operations, as opposed to arrays.

Comment: @bugs thanks for the info! Do you happen to know how to replace the array with a map and push the paths into it?

Comment: Is that file name search the only thing you're using that `cache` for?

Comment: I think you're looking for `cacheElement.endsWith(filename)`, not `includes`.

Comment: @Bergi I also planning to search for directories names, not just file names. Thanks for the suggestion about `cacheElement.endsWith` I'm gonna use that in case when "fizzy" search not needed!